# Do you keep campaign achievements earned during an unfinished mission in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Thus far every time I have earned a campaign achievement in StarCraft 2 I have also finished its associated campaign mission. This is fine when playing a mission for the first time but on subsequent replays I'd rather just earn the achievement and then quit the mission.

Which leads me to my question: if you don't finish or abort a mission do earned achievements stick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you do. As long as you see the popup notifying you that you earned an achievement, it's yours regardless of whether or not you finish the current mission.

Comment: He is correct. Obviously, achievements that aren't **earned** before the end of the mission "win in under 10 minutes" don't get earned unless you finish.