# Reinstalled Starcraft 2 (new system), lost my achievements

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I recently changed my system drive (C:) and did a clean Windows (8) reinstall. When I reinstalled Starcraft 2 (which I hadn't been playing for quite a long while), the game asked me to create a new character and start a new campaign. Therefore, all my achievements, progress and saved games don't appear any more in the game.

From what I read, those informations are stored locally, in the "My Documents" folder. Both in my previous and current config,  I have set Windows to store this folder on another drive (D:), so this folder hasn't been erased when I reinstalled Windows, and all my data form my previous SC2 install is still there: I can see the folder of my previous character (and it's 500MB worth of data), but for some reason the game ignores this folder and creates a new, empty profile.

I also have a backup of this folder somewhere else, so I tried uninstalling SC2 (with the option to erase local saved data), restoring this folder from the backup and reinstalling SC2, but it didn't change anything. When I log in, I still access my new, empty character.

How do I force the game to use my old character ?

(I also still have access to my entire old C: drive, if that helps.)

(**Edit:** I tried to ask this question on the battlenet forums (http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/13438/), but it says I have a "trial account" and must upgrade to a full account in order to create a forum thread. I don't even know what this means...)

(**Edit 2: problem solved.** See my answer below.)

(**Edit 3:** see the accepted answer for the real explanation of the problem, though. ^^)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably, you have redownloaded a version for a **wrong region** of the game. EU forums are full of people who accidentally logged in to the Americas.

Recenty, Blizzard has begun preparing to launch Global Play with the release of Heart of the Swarm. They have converted any regional licenses of Starcraft II to global ones. This means you can now download any language version (if you have a non-restricted license) and play in any region with it.

The problem is, until March 12, there is no "Region" button in the UI, so you can still only log in to the region corresponding to your game language.

**Fixes:**

To the game:

- Go to "Download games" on Battle.net, look for a "Change" link, switch to your language version and redownload the game.
- Wait for March 12, click "Region" on the login screen and log in to the correct region.
- Use a hack to enable region selection in the current version: see [this post](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=395154), look for "regions.xml". Note that mentioning this is forbidden on Battle.net forums.

To the website profile:

```
http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/327959/1/Orc/
        \__ server                         \__ realm code
```

- The website actually should be perfectly fine, you just need to find the right one :) Check if you are logging in to the right Battle.net, and then try to find your profile. I am not sure how to navigate to different realm characters on the same server, but I'd assume it allows to select what character you are logging in with when you do.

Comment: Well, you seem to be right. :) I just went to my profile on the web and found the region menu, which is located on the bottom right of the page (not very obvious, though). Switching from "Americas" to "Europe" made indeed my old profile reappear. Thank you for your answer! But FYI, comparing the URLs to both profile, there's no "realm code" part. Old profile: http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/586355/1/Severian/ New profile: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/4264071/1/Severian/ So apparently, what changes is only the server prefix (us/eu) and the player id.

Comment: Oh, right, the region menu, forgot about that :) The realm code is right there in both URLs, though - note the `/1/` right before `Severian` - it is just that both realms are №1 on their respective servers. For example, realm "Russia" is #2 on EU server.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to copy an old savegame from `C:\Users\%youruser%\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\%youraccountnumber%\%someothernumbers%\Saves\Campaign` to your new `Starcraft II\...\Campaign` folder and load it. All the local achievements and campaign progress is loaded from the "last used savegame".

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really work. The game now shows that I finished the campaign (and I get a "resume" button), but I still doesn't have any achievement...

Comment: OK I solved it (see my answer). I guess your solution works fine if the saved data has already through the "optimization" process I mention.

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved it by first restoring my whole Starcraft II folder (containing the game files) to its previous state (from my old system) and also restoring the Starcraft II folder in "My Documents" to its previous state (old system).

So I basically returned the whole game (game folder **and** player data) to the state they were on my old system.

Then when I launched the game, it first asked me to wait for 15-20 minutes while the game files were "optimized". Then it installed various patches until the game was up to date. This finally gave me access to my old player profile with all the achievements.

So my guess is that the "optimization" was necessary to be able to continue to use my player data with the latest version of the game.
Since I first installed it in its latest version directly, my player data didn't go through that optimization process and weren't recognized.

Comment: While you were able to solve your issue I'm not sure it was the root cause, [see my answer for what I think happened](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107382/559).

Comment: You are right about the "optimization" part, that is just the process of updating. But this has no relation to your player data, it only optimizes game's resources. The problem was that you have downloaded the wrong regional version of Starcraft, so it logged you into the wrong realm. Old client, of course, was the correct one. See [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107503/33619) for details.

Answer (score 1):

While [your solution worked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107348/559) to solve your issue, I think you missed the key to your problem:

> the game asked me to create a new character and start a new campaign

Had you not created a new account your campaign progress and achievements would have been listed even with a fresh install.

Achievements and campaign progress are stored on Blizzard's Battle.net servers. In fact, to earn achievements you have to be connected to the internet (they do this to cut down on cheating). To further bolster the case for server side storage you can [view my StarCraft 2 achievements gallery](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/343464/1/ahsteele/achievements/).

While I haven't recently performed a repave on my Windows box previous repaves worked without issue. Anecdotally logging into StarCraft 2 from the same Battle.net account on my Mac shows all of my achievements and allows me to continue the campaign. Until a week ago I had never installed StarCraft 2 on this machine (I'm getting excited for [HOTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft_II:_Heart_of_the_Swarm)). It is important to note that this does not work for any mid mission save games. Only allowing me to start from missions I've completed.

With all of that said I go back to the fact that you created a new account. Without creating a new account your achievements and campaign progress would have been available as soon as you logged in.

Finally I asked similar questions a few years ago:

- [What happens to my campaign progress if I uninstall StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3666/559)
- [Do you keep campaign achievements earned during an unfinished mission in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4044/559)

**Edit**

Your [comment that you had ***not*** created a new account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107337/reinstalled-starcraft-2-new-system-lost-my-achievements/107382#comment144208_107382), threw the premise of what I thought was causing the issue out the window. However, it is disconcerting as the above still holds true: both achievements and campaign progress are maintained on Battle.net servers. If when you logged in with your existing account your campaign and achievements were not listed there is definitely something else at play. Your best bet would be to contact [Blizzard Support](https://us.battle.net/support/en/ticket/submit) to work towards a resolution.

Comment: To be clear: I did not created a new _account_. I used the same email as always, with the same password, and I did not activate the game again. And like I said, my saved data were always in the same folder ("My Documents\Starcraft II" on D:), yet when I first launched the game after my first attempt to reinstall it, it asked me to create a new character like if it was the first time I played. I don't remember seeing any option to load a previous character instead of creating one, so unless I missed it (does such an option exist?), I don't think I had a choice _not_ to create a new character.

Comment: That being said, you do raised a valid (and somewhat concerning) point. While my solution made all my achievements appear again _in the game_, when I log in on my BattleNet account (on the web), I still see my new, almost empty character (with which I played about 3 games vs AI --couldn't resist-- which gave me a few XP). However, I must say that I haven't played again after I solved my problem, so I hope this is just a temporary situation, and that playing it again will sync it entirely with the web. Unless it triggers some anti-cheat mechanism which would block the syncing... :-(

Comment: @s427 whoops I misconstrued your statement to mean that you had created a new account. ;) Since you are using the same account and your achievements are not listed online I would contact Blizzard customer support. Seems like there's something else at play.

Comment: @s427 added a bit of info about contact Blizzard support (not that it really changes the answer). Best of luck if you do contact support I'd be curious to know what their resolution to the issue is.

Comment: @s427 I haven't played SC2 recently but a while back they said they are releasing "Global Play", which means you can chose any region to play on with the same account but the characters are different on each region. If that is already released as i assume it is, did you maybe select the wrong region to play on? Or did you maybe download a version for a different region?

Comment: @ahsteele: Thanks! I'll make sure I update this page if I get more information. I was wondering that maybe when SC2 was first released, it didn't sync all that data on the cloud, and that this was introduced later on (after I temporarily stopped playing)...? Has your profile and achievements gallery always been accessible on the web? I don't remember that being the case for me (but maybe I just missed it somehow).

Comment: @dbemerlin: Thanks for the info. After a little googling, I found this official FAQ: https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-global-play-faq I don't recall seeing an option to switch region on the login screen of the game (I can't check right now as I'm not at home), so I assume Global Play hasn't been officially released yet (I saw a post mentioning it would be released around the same time as HotS).

Comment: @s427 achievements and campaign progress have always been server side. I asked the question [What happens to my campaign progress if I uninstall StarCraft 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3666/559) on the day StarCraft 2: WoL was released: July 27th, 2010. The answers to that question indicate server side recording even then.

Comment: @ahsteele: OK thanks. It would indeed seem strange that a game this big, in 2010, would have overlooked storing user progress on the server. ^^

Comment: @dbemerlin: well, it seems you were on the right track after all. :) It seems my problem was indeed caused by me being logged into the wrong region of the game. See the accepted answer for more details.

Comment: @s427 glad you got it worked out. Sorry I didn't think about the region stuff. ;)

Comment: @ahsteele you don't have to be sorry, I assure you. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me with my problem. :)